Identify cells in the selected range that are referenced by formulas in other sheets
I want to identify and select cells in the selected range that are referenced by formulas in other sheets.
The macro I built returns mixed results, sometimes returning cells that don't have any direct dependents in other sheets, and sometimes not selecting those.
Sub FindDependentsInOtherSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim formulaCell As Range
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Dim dependentFound As Boolean
    Dim formulaText As String
    Dim formulaCells As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String

    Set rng = Selection
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsSource = rng.Worksheet

    ' Initialize outputRange to Nothing
    Set outputRange = Nothing

    ' Loop through each cell in the selected range
    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            GoTo NextCell
        End If
        
        dependentFound = False
        cellAddress = "'" & wsSource.Name & "'!" & cell.Address(False, False)
        
        ' Loop through each worksheet in the active workbook to find formulas referencing the cell
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> wsSource.Name Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set formulaCells = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not formulaCells Is Nothing Then
                    For Each formulaCell In formulaCells
                        formulaText = formulaCell.Formula
                        ' Check if the formula references the cell
                        If InStr(1, formulaText, cellAddress, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            dependentFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next formulaCell
                End If
                If dependentFound Then Exit For
            End If
        Next ws
        
        ' If a dependent is found in another sheet, add the cell to the output range
        If dependentFound Then
            If outputRange Is Nothing Then
                Set outputRange = cell
            Else
                Set outputRange = Union(outputRange, cell)
            End If
        End If

NextCell:
    Next cell

    ' Select the output range if any cells found
    If Not outputRange Is Nothing Then
        outputRange.Select
        MsgBox "Cells that are direct precedents to other sheets have been selected.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No direct precedents found in other sheets for the selected range.", vbInformation
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

I expect to loop through each cell in the selected range and check if there are any formulas in other sheets that reference the cells in my selected range.
If a dependent is found, add the cell to the output range.
Finally, if any cells are found, select the output range.
The end result thus, is the selection of cells from my selected range that have dependents.

Your code line below has some bugs:

If there is no space in wsSource.Name, the single quotation mark (') does not appear in the cell formula. eg. ZZZ1 is not a valid cell address.
Cell references in formulas can vary in format: absolute reference, relative reference, or a mix of both. eg: A1, $A$1, $A1, A$1

cellAddress = "'" & wsSource.Name & "'!" & cell.Address(False, False)

Simply looking for the cell reference as a string in the formula is unreliable. For example:

If the source sheet is Sheet1 and the Selection is A2
The formula on other sheets could be =SUM(Sheet1!A1:A3), where A2 is not explicitly shown.



The code below extracts all cell references from formulas and checks if they intersect with the selected range (Selection on the source sheet).

The regex pattern (\$*[A-Z]{1,3}\$*\d{1,7}) only roughly matches cell references. It may incorrectly identify other strings in formulas.

Note: The Union method is used to merge the desired range, so the dependent cells should be from the same sheet. Otherwise, a warning message box will appear. You could add more code to handle it for each sheet individually.


Option Explicit
Sub FindDependentsInOtherSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim formulaCell As Range
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Dim dependentFound As Boolean
    Dim formulaText As String
    Dim formulaCells As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String
    Set rng = Selection
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set wsSource = rng.Worksheet
    Dim strMatch As String, j As Long, sShtName As String
    Dim objRegExp As Object, objMatch As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    sShtName = wsSource.Name
    If InStr(sShtName, " ") > 0 Then sShtName = "'" & sShtName & "'"
    objRegExp.Pattern = sShtName & "!\$*[A-Z]{1,3}\$*\d{1,7}(:\$*[A-Z]{1,3}\$*\d{1,7})*"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegExp.MultiLine = False
    ' Initialize outputRange to Nothing
    Set outputRange = Nothing
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the active workbook to find formulas referencing the cell
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsSource.Name Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set formulaCells = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not formulaCells Is Nothing Then
                For Each formulaCell In formulaCells
                    formulaText = formulaCell.Formula
                    ' Check if the formula references the cell
                    Set objMatch = objRegExp.Execute(formulaText)
                    If objMatch.Count > 0 Then
                        For j = 0 To objMatch.Count - 1
                            strMatch = objMatch(j).Value
                            If Not Application.Intersect(Range(strMatch), rng) Is Nothing Then
                                If outputRange Is Nothing Then
                                    Set outputRange = formulaCell
                                Else
                                    If formulaCell.Parent.Name <> outputRange.Parent.Name Then
                                        MsgBox "Can't handle direct precedents cells on multiple sheets:" & _
                                            vbCr & formulaCell.Parent.Name & vbTab & outputRange.Parent.Name
                                        Exit Sub
                                    Else
                                        Set outputRange = Union(outputRange, formulaCell)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next formulaCell
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    If Not outputRange Is Nothing Then
        outputRange.Parent.Activate
        outputRange.Select
        MsgBox "Cells that are direct precedents to other sheets have been selected.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No direct precedents found in other sheets for the selected range.", vbInformation
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub


I think the macro I am looking for is to  select (identify) the cells in my selected range that referenced by cells in other sheets via a formula.
you raised a really good point when a formula like sum(a1:a3) will exclude a2.
I tried your code but it did not work. what can I do?

did not work doesn't provide any information. Show sample data / formula in your post ahd specify what's the matter.

If you treat all dependent cells equally, like the Workbook.SheetCalculate() event does, you can use it to achieve your aim.
Firstly, you must code this event, which involves the following procedure
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If TypeName(Sh) = "Worksheet" Then
        If Not Sh Is ActiveSheet Then otherSheets = True
    End If
End Sub

(this gif shows where to put this code)
Then the main procedure is
Public otherSheets As Boolean
Sub testDependents()
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    'required for calc event
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cellContents() As String
    ReDim cellContents(1 To Selection.Count)
    Dim cell As Range, outputRange As Range
    Dim cellCounter As Long
    cellCounter = 1
    For Each cell In Selection
        cellContents(cellCounter) = cell.Formula
        otherSheets = False
        cell.ClearContents
        If otherSheets Then 'a sheet-calculate event was triggered
            If results Is Nothing Then
                Set outputRange = cell
            Else
                Set outputRange = Union(outputRange, cell)
            End If
        End If
        cellCounter = cellCounter + 1
    Next cell
    cellCounter = 1
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'ensure only 1 calc event for all cells
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Formula = cellContents(cellCounter)
        cellCounter = cellCounter + 1
    Next cell
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Not results Is Nothing Then
        outputRange.Select
        MsgBox "Cells that are referenced by formulae in other sheets have been selected.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No references found in other sheets for the selected range.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub

This approach involves iterating through all of your selected cells, and in each iteration

storing the current cell's contents
clearing the cell
recording whether or not the Calculate event in any other sheet was called

As this approach requires automatic calculation to be enabled, its efficiency
(or otherwise) will, largely, be determined by the number and complexity of your formulae.
